# Java: Access level of Inner classes

Tags: java, class, nested, inner-classes

I was about to create a class inside another class

```
public class Sq {
        class Inner {
            private int a; //no getters setters
                           //a is private
            private Inner (int a1) {
                this.a = a1;
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sq outter = new Sq();
        Inner d = outter.new Inner(3);
        System.out.println("Private a = " + d.a);
    }
}
```

It works.. so that i can get access to inner's **private** fields, also i've added Inner2 class and tried to change "a" from the Inner2 and it also worked :/

So looks like **private** in the inner class **is not so private**, looks like **it's public** within the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested classes are `public` for the outer class and `private` for all the others classes...

Some reference: [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Declaring `private` the nested/inner class does not change the visibility to the outer class itself, just think the nested class (private or not) as a variable/method of the outer class.

```
public class Sq {
    public int publicNumber = 0;
    private int number = 0;
    private class Inner { ... }
}
```

**EDIT**

From the inner class you can also call some variable/method of the outer class and otherwise without problem

```
public class Sq {

    private int number = 0;

    class Inner {
        private int a;

        private Inner(int a1) {
            this.a = a1;
            number++;
        }

        private String getOuterClassString()
        {
            return getOuterString();
        }

        private String getPrivateString()
        {
            return "privateString";
        }

        public String getPublicString()
        {
            return "publicString";
        }
    }

    private String getOuterString()
    {
        return "outerString";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sq outter = new Sq();
        Inner d = outter.new Inner(3);
        System.out.println("Number = " + outter.number);
        System.out.println("Private a = " + d.a);
        System.out.println("Number = " + outter.number);

        System.out.println(d.getPrivateString());
        System.out.println(d.getPublicString());
        System.out.println(d.getOuterClassString());
    }
}
```

Comment: so all fields and methods inside the nested class are public for outer?

Comment: I edited my answer with a better example of getter and variable access from the outer and inner classes...

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes are ultimately meant to provide some utility to the outer class in terms of organization.  The inner class is completely accessible to the outer class, because ultimately you really should never need to *hide* data from your own class.  When the complexity of your code requires you to hide data behind getters and setters, you should be seriously considering the possibility of putting that class in its own file.